# What's the best jQuery plugin for this job?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am looking for a good jQuery plugin for this case.

A page shows a list of products. When a product is clicked, the product detail information is displayed as div layer at the same page and other things at the background are blurred. And users can add the product to cart there or uses can close it and the background comes back.

It's basically like Lightbox plugin function but it shows general info not just an image.

Can you suggest a good plugin for this?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Comment: A simple google search for "jquery modal popup" should give you everything you need to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal favourite is the jQuery based fancyBox plugin.

[Fancybox plugin link](http://fancybox.net/)

It would allow for gallery based grouping of image dialogs with custom HTML content to be displayed per item as per your requirement.

With regards to the ecommerce aspect, you'd probably need to tweak the dialog plugin yourself to achieve this as the purpose of the dialog plugins are usually very specific to UI rendering and not designed for a specific use.

Comment: Fancybox looks good. The Iframe example will work for my needs. Thanks.

Comment: @Sam: Great, hope it works out well for you. Feel free to update this page with any help comments you need.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleModal: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: Voted this down, simplemodal is not longer developed / maintained as it should be - waiting months for merging pull requests...